# Window.print() does not take the current url

Tags: javascript, printing, window

I am using the following code. According to this code, new window will open with the source of url given. But when printing, it is showing about:blank is printing. The page loads correctly. Before loading, the page url is also about:blank. But it changes to the given url soon.

```
var url="http://localhost:8080/hiring/docs/Keneth%20_1340800082258/Keneth%20_resume_1340800082258.pdf";
var printwindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'fullScreen=yes');
//setTimeout('2000');
printwindow.focus();
printwindow.print();
```

Comment: Have you tried it with a simple website?

Comment: I found one here - http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/7/. it works for all other links except mine.

Comment: I have noticed that you tries to print a PDF just now, I don't think that it is possible to print the PDF file just because you can see it in the browser. It's just a Adobe Reader plugin, because of the same reason you can't print the flash movies on the page

Answer (score 1):

I guess `window.print()` runs before the page is actually loaded, because it takes microseconds to execute next command of your code, but the page won't load in microseconds, that's why it prints blank page, try print it after document load event.

**FIX**

I have noticed that you tries to print a PDF just now, I don't think that it is possible to print the PDF file just because you can see it in the browser. It's just an Adobe Reader plugin, because of the same reason you can't print the flash movies on the page

Comment: printwindow.onload is not a function error. I tried with the above answer also. That will not trigger print

Comment: you have to access the `document` object of that window, than use onload on that object

Comment: I found one here - jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/7. it works for all other links except mine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
printwindow.onload = function() {
  printwindow.focus();
  printwindow.print();
};
```

Comment: will not enter into the function. I put alert to check.

Comment: I found one here - jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/7. it works for all other links except mine.

Comment: Your link is a PDF, this is why it fails, I am not aware of a way to auto-print a pdf from JS