# window.print() works on urls except one

Tags: javascript, printing, window

What is the difference between these links(iframe src)? window.print() works on

```
var myWindow=window.open('','','fullscreen=yes');
myWindow.document.write("<iframe src=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447382/window-print-does-not-take-the-current-url\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe>");
myWindow.document.write('<iframe src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');myWindow.document.close();                            
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
```

But not works on

```
myWindow.document.write("<iframe src=\"http://localhost:8080/hiringsteps/docs/Keneth _1340800082258/Keneth _resume_1340800082258.pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is PDF file, not HTML one.